# docker-compose is not saving data to volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Below is my docker-compose file in which I specified, that the postgres data is saved into my folder in the host called `volumes/db_data/`. But this folder stays empty. Instead, the data seems to be saved into the default folder `var/lib/docker/volumes`. Also, the folder `user_models` is not saved locally in `volumes/user_models`. The `api_server.log` is also not saved. Therefore I guess there is something wrong with my understanding of docker volumes in general.

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxxxx
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: user-db
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  api-server:
    image: api-server
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/user_models:/classification/user_models
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 1337:1337

  model-trainer:
    image: webapp-trainer
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/user_models:/user_models
      - ./volumes/api_server.log:/api_server.log
    depends_on:
      - db

  react-client:
    image: webapp-client
    depends_on:
      - api-server
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Everything else is working fine, just the data in `user_models` is not saved and the postgres data is saved in the wrong place. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**
docker-compose up prints this at the start:

WARNING: Service "db" is using volume "/var/lib/postgresql/data" from the previous container. Host mapping "/home/theo/Documents/Programming/cbi-webapp/compose/volumes/db_data"

yet db_data is empty

Comment: Hello, could you try to replace `./` with `${PWD}/` ?

Comment: @EtienneDijon yes, it gives me:
```WARNING: The PWD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Recreating compose_db_1 ... 
WARNING: Service "db" is using volume "/var/lib/postgresql/data" from the previous container. Host mapping "/volumes/db_data" has no effect. Remove the existingRecreating compose_db_1 ... done```

Comment: Could you try to : `docker-compose down`, then change permissions of your `volumes` directory, for each image instance, add enough permissions so it is rwx for your container user. You may try with smaller compose file, testing each service.